# Delete All Data Found With Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a database project, and for sanity's sake I want to delete all of my problem data from the database while I test it's other features.

I currently have some queries written up to help me find my problem data sets like the code below:

```
SELECT Order_ID, Part_Number, COUNT(*)
FROM Temp_A
GROUP BY Order_ID, Part_Number
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Now I want to be able to delete all of the data I find with these query from my Temp Table.  However putting the code in:

```
DELETE FROM Temp_A
WHERE IN (/*MY QUERY*/)
```

Doesn't seem to work, as I am getting a Syntax error.  I've tried removing the `IN`, changing the `WHERE` to `WITH`, I am not sure exactly how to structure this query to get it to do what I want it to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be using an `INNER JOIN`:

```
DELETE A
FROM Temp_A A
INNER JOIN (SELECT Order_ID, Part_Number, COUNT(*)
            FROM Temp_A
            GROUP BY Order_ID, Part_Number
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) B
    ON A.Order_ID = B.Order_ID
    AND A.Part_Number = B.Part_Number
;
```

If you are using SQL Server 2005+, then you can use a `CTE`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            N = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY OrderID, Part_Number)
    FROM Temp_A
)
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE N > 1
;
```

Comment: This worked for me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

can you delete by the Order_ID? if so you could technically try the following

```
DELETE FROM Temp_A
where Order_ID IN(
   SELECT Order_ID
   FROM Temp_A
   GROUP BY Order_ID, Part_Number
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

This will select the same select list you included above, but only actually select the Order_ID, thus returning your list of Order_ID's to delete with

As pointed out however, this will only work if Order_ID is a primary key! eep, so not perfect i admit

Comment: But what if there's a combination of `Order_Id` and `Part_Number` that appears just once, and the same `Order_Id` and another `Part_Number` appear more than once?....you'll delete every result for that `Order_Id`

Comment: You're right :O i guess i'm taking a huge assumption that Order_ID is a non-duplicatable primary key. I guess my idea will only work in that scenario, i will update my question